# android BaseFragment with it's own xml and inherited fragment's view inside a parent's frameLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I have an abstract fragment that has it's own view (views the are common for inherited fragments)
I'm creating a fragment that inherit from that base fragment and it has it's own view (layout)
How can it be done?
I'm getting an error that says that I need to call remove view first...

The inherited Fragment's view should go into the: (Found in the parent's xml)

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/gamePadContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gamePadHistoryScroller"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Base Fragment (abstract):

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gamepad, container, false)

        val gamePadView = inflater.inflate(onFragmentLayoutRequest(), null)
        gamePadView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
            ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                joystickLeftCenter[0] = 0
                joystickLeftCenter[1] = 0

                joystickRightCenter[0] = 0
                joystickRightCenter[1] = 0

                gamePadButtonsMap[KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_THUMBL]?.let {
                    joystickLeftCenter[0] = it.buttonView.left
                    joystickLeftCenter[1] = it.buttonView.top
                }

                gamePadButtonsMap[KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_THUMBR]?.let {
                    joystickRightCenter[0] = it.buttonView.left
                    joystickRightCenter[1] = it.buttonView.top
                }

                gamePadView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            }
        })
        gamePadButtonsMap = onGamePadButtonMapRequest(gamePadView)

        return rootView
    }
```

Base fragment XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/gamePadContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gamePadHistoryScroller"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!--  Buttons History  -->
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/gamePadHistoryScroller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.265"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:id="@+id/gamePadHistoryContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
            android:background="@color/bg_buttons_history"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Inherit fragment:

```
class PS4Fragment : GamePadFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ps4, container, false)
    }
}
```

Comment: do you need to add a view into the container present in the parent xml?? if that is the case, then call super.onCreateView from the child and, add the inflated child view to the parent views container.

Comment: Please check updated question...I need to do this by code.. not from the XML
can you demonstrate what you mean by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gamepad, container, false)

        val gamePadView = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(onFragmentLayoutRequest(), rootView.gamePadContainer, true)

        gamePadButtonsMap = onGamePadButtonMapRequest(gamePadView)
```

rootView.gamePadContainer.addView(gamePadView)
            return rootView
        }

I've been using the same inflater.. now it's working as expected.
In the child fragment (Inherit fragment) there is no "onCreateView"

Now, 
I have a base fragment with some views and component that all fragments have, and a unique view to each fragment :)

Thanks!